# Caving proposal

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a new [caving proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50482/caving) in Area 51.  It seems to me that most, if not all the sample questions that got upvoted would fit perfectly well in TGO.  So far they only have 12 followers, with 2 of us also active here.  I wonder if they should be invited here.  I feel that a separate caving proposal does not have much chance of making it through, and we could use the extra questions.  One can perhaps object that caves and mines are not really "outdoors", but I think the topic does belong here.

Answer (score 9):

I think caving is perfectly fine here. Caves may be sheltered, but they're still nature.

Comment: We have climbing here - we can go up, so why not down also! :)

Answer (score 4):

Caving/spelunking is certainly welcome here in my opinion! I think it would be a great addition.